# Pulling current price for a stock into existing pandas data frame (python) using Bloomberg API / pybbg

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bloomberg

```
import pybbg_k as pybbg
import blpapi
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import pandas as pd

bbg = pybbg.Pybbg()
bbg.service_refData()
```

I have a list of tickers in the following existing pandas data frame (df1)

```
    4   BBG_Ticker
    0   MSFT US Equity
    1   AAPL US Equity
    2   IBM US Equity
```

## adding column 'Price' to df1 pulling stock price using BBG API

```
df1['Price'] = bbg.bdp(df1['BBG_Ticker'], 'last_price').iloc[0, 0]

    4   BBG_Ticker      Price
    0   MSFT US Equity  154.55
    1   AAPL US Equity  154.55
    2   IBM US Equity   154.55
```

I am getting the price for MSFT US Equity for all stocks. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

You need to join the result with your original dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'BBG_Ticker': [ 'MSFT US Equity', 'AAPL US Equity', 'IBM US Equity']});
df1.join(bbg.bdp(df1['BBG_Ticker'], 'last_price').loc['last_price'], how='left', on=['BBG_Ticker'])
```

```
    BBG_Ticker      last_price
0   MSFT US Equity  12.345
1   AAPL US Equity  83.332
2   IBM US Equity   91.231
```

Comment: Thank you Dr. Bloomberger! this solution works. just for me to understand, why is it not possible to just add a column to the existing dataframe without creating a new df and then having to join them? thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do below instead:

```
In [1]: from xbbg import blp
In [2]: blp.bdp(['MSFT US Equity', 'AAPL US Equity', 'IBM US Equity'], 'last_price')
Out[2]:
                last_price
MSFT US Equity      161.49
AAPL US Equity      308.39
IBM US Equity       136.32
```

Reference: [xbbg](https://xbbg.readthedocs.io/)